# code to make dialog box or popup Menu in iphone

Tags: iphone

i need to open dialog box or popup Menu on the button click.But i didn't find the concept of dialog box in iphone.can anybody tell me how to make dialog box or popup Menu in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `UIAlerView` or you can use the `UIActionSheet` to provide popup menu features.

Comment: Is there any other option than these two?

Comment: Other option is you only have to create a custom view just similar to popup menu. In iPad you can use `UIPopoverController`.