# How to make dialog box in iphone

Tags: iphone

I need to open the dialog box when the user clicks on a  button . How can I do this programmatically in iphone.

Comment: Do you mean a *custom* dialog box, or a standard `UIAlertView` message box?

Comment: (You've also asked this before.) possible duplicate of [code to make dialog box or popup Menu in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735789/code-to-make-dialog-box-or-popup-menu-in-iphone)

Comment: i need to make a custom dialog box not UIAlertView or UIActionSheet.

Comment: What you should have learned from the lack of good answers to your last question was that your question(s) are vague and difficult to answer. No one really knows what you're trying to do, so they can't give you very good suggestions. Rather than posting another question, you should focus on improving the original. Or at least make the second one more clear as to what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Define what you mean by a dialog box, and exactly how that is different from either a UIAlertView, or another UIViewController + UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a UIAlertView. You should download the [UICatlog example from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/AlertsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-AlertsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4), it has examples all of the UI objects in action, plus their names.

Comment: i need to make a custom dialog box not UIAlertView or UIActionSheet.

Comment: UICatlog example from Apple is the best one ....Why don,t you are trying to take something from this catlog..they are easiar as compared to custom dialog box that you are asking

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an equivalent of your standard desktop UI dialog box - you should probably be subclassing UIView and displaying it modally.  See [presentModalViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a)